# $G$ is a simple graph with no triangles,let $β(G)$ be the maximum number of independent vertices.Show $Δ(G) \le β(G)$ and $|E(G)| \le (|V(G)|*β(G))/2$

Tags: graph-theory

For the first part of the question, I thought we could use contradiction. Suppose there is a vertex $u$
that has a greater degree of $β(G)$, $deg(u) = β(G) + 1$.

The neighbors of $u$ form a set $(N)$ of $β(G) + 1$ vertices, a set that is bigger than $β(G)$, so there must be an edge connecting a pair of vertices from the $N$ set else $β(G)$ wouldn't be the maximum number of independent vertices.
Since those vertices are also connected to $u$ they form a triangle which is a contradiction to the hypothesis.

For the second part,using the Handshaking Lemma the number of edges are upper bound by the vertices having maximum degree $Δ(G)$, which in turn is upper bound by $β(G)$.

$2*m \le (|V(G)| - β(G)) * β(G) = |V(G)| * β(G) - β(G)^2 $ , $ β(G)^2 \ge 0 $

Finally, $ m \le (|V(G)| * β(G)) / 2$ .

Comment: For the first part, you don't want to include vertex $u$ *and* its neighbors, since of course there are some edges there. Just let $N$ be the set of neighbors.

Comment: You are correct,I am gonna edit that,thank you!